# How to extract MXF file data?

Tags: python, ffmpeg, mxf

Is there any way to extract MXF (Material Exchange Format) file data using python?

All I want to do is get data like video duration, actual video stream and if possible the voice in mp3 or any audio format from an MXF file.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can do those things using [ffmpeg-python](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python).

Example of how to extract video duration:

```
import ffmpeg
filename = 'sample_960x400_ocean_with_audio.mxf'

# Get duration
# Credit: https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python/issues/545#issuecomment-836792082
video_info = ffmpeg.probe(filename)
duration = float(video_info['format']['duration'])
print(f'Duration: {duration} seconds')
```

Example of how to convert the audio to MP3:

```
import ffmpeg
filename = 'sample_960x400_ocean_with_audio.mxf'

# Load file
in_file = ffmpeg.input(filename)

# Get audio track, convert to mp3
in_file.output('file.mp3').run()
```

Example of how to convert the audio and video to mp4:

```
import ffmpeg
filename = 'sample_960x400_ocean_with_audio.mxf'

# Load file
in_file = ffmpeg.input(filename)

# Get video, convert to mp4
in_file.output('file.mp4').run()
```

Note that to use ffmpeg-python, you must install both ffmpeg-python and ffmpeg. See the [documentation](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python#installation) for more.

Comment: Thanks! It worked for me! Both seem to work fine also is there any way to extract subtitles as well?

Comment: @Rex Can you give an example of a MXF file with subtitles? I don't have one.

Comment: Sorry what I meant by that was can we get a text format of whatever is being spoken in the video. The video itself doesn't have subtitles. I fixed that by using the extracted audio and running a speech to text API. Thanks!